# Parent's ng-class-odd in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="object in data">
    <!-- parent -->
    <section id="{{object.tag}}"  ng-class-odd="'content text-center light'" ng-class-even="'content text-center dark'">
    ...
        <!-- child -->
        <p ng-repeat="record in object.records">
            {{record.title}} <a href="/#/r/{{record._id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">read</a>
        </p>
    ...

    </section>
</div>
```

If the parent class **is light**, I need **btn-primary** in my second lopp, if the parent class **is dark**, I need **btn-default** in my second loop.

I use **ng-class-odd** and **ng-class-even** for my **parent class**, but how can I detect that in **my second loop**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even better than using parent `$index` you can use

```
<p ng-repeat="record in object.records">
    {{record.title}} <a href="/#/r/{{record._id}}" class="btn btn-xs" ng-class="{'btn-primary': $parent.$even, 'btn-default': $parent.$odd}">read</a>
</p>
```

Comment: This is the best solution I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$parent.$index` for this.

Change your inner loop to:

```
<p ng-repeat="record in object.records">
    {{record.title}} <a href="/#/r/{{record._id}}" class="btn btn-xs" ng-class="{'btn-primary': $parent.$index%2 != 0, 'btn-default': $parent.$index%2 == 0}">read</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access `$parent.$index`

like this: 
`<a ng-if="$parent.$index%2==0" href="/#/r/{{record._id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">read</a>
<a ng-if="$parent.$index%2!=0" href="/#/r/{{record._id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">read</a>`

see working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/2773/